# Disable Type Checking in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way of disabling Mongoose from checking the types when saving?

I'm converting a bunch of documents to a newer format, so type checking isn't super-important for me (after running the conversion scripts the data will all be in the correct format/ location).

Any ideas?  I thought about disabling the `strict` option in the various schemas, but that seems to be for fields that weren't defined in the schema rather than disabling type checking.

Comment: Have you looked at using the native driver instead of Mongoose?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Yep, I'm aware I can get around it using the native driver or other lower-level packages (`mongoskin` for example).

Comment: Are you opposed to modifying your schema files?  You could change them to [`Mixed`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) which would allow anything (no verification).

Comment: @dylants I am.  I know this is a possibility, but the idea was to leverage existing code already in place to assist in the conversions.  Setting the type to `Mixed` would cause issues in the actual code base (having to `.markModified()` on the specified fields, for example).  Points for trying to help though!

Comment: And just to be clear, this isn't so much a "my scripts aren't working" question as much as a "is this possible to do in Mongoose currently" type of thing.  If the general consensus is that it's impossible, this might be something worth adding into the library.

Comment: It's interesting, in testing, I haven't had to use the `markModified()` function to persist the changes to a Mixed schema type.  For example, schema defined as: `var TestSchema = new Schema({ someField: {} });`.  Creating an instance of the model using this schema, setting it's `someField`, then saving it, shows up in the database.  I've seen that you have to use `markModified` in the documentation as well, but haven't investigated _why_ they require this.

Comment: @dylants I've definitely had this bite me before in production, I wouldn't assume `Mixed` changes are being saved without the `.markModified()` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So unless someone can prove otherwise, there isn't a way inside Mongoose to disable type checking as far as I can tell (without altering the schemas).

It is unfortunate, but not insurmountable.